# Google Talk XMPP - What is X-GOOGLE-TOKEN?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I'm trying to authenticate to Google Talk. The `X-OAUTH2` mechanism, which uses OAuth2 tokens, is [well documented](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth). But what is `X-GOOGLE-TOKEN` and where is it documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, found it. It's the [deprecated ClientLogin API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps):

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.